# Meaning of "enduring fevers"

Tags: phrase-meaning

From [a research paper](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyt.2017.00174/full#B10):

> How can such a diverse group of pathogens confer similar risks of psychotic disorder? Common to the implicated pathogens is the maternal immune response. In support of this possibility, **enduring fevers** above a certain threshold pose the greatest risk (10).

Do the authors mean "fevers that are enduring" (fevers **that last long**) and which produce a body temperature above a certain threshold"?

Or do they mean "for a future mother, **being in a state of fever** (enduring a fever) for a period of time that exceeds a certain threshold is to put herself at the greatest risk" of maternal immune response?

Comment: If they'd meant to say the latter, the sentence would read *...poses the greatest risk*.

Comment: [...[similar risks to those of a psychotic disorder. "Enduring fevers" means: a person enduring fevers. Being subjected to fevers above a certain threshold. As in:  "Enduring a fever is not my favorite pass time." Being subjected to a fever.

Comment: I agree, but the authors are all non-native speakers, and an error could have easily been missed by a reviewer. I would say that this is ambiguous. Reading the cited paper (https://www.biologicalpsychiatryjournal.com/article/S0006-3223(13)00946-3/fulltext) could answer this.

Comment: "Enduring" can mean "long-lasting", e.g. a poet of enduring greatness, the enduring appeal of cartoons, I shall be left with many enduring memories of the time I spent in India.

Comment: Intensity (max temp) and duration of the fever are commonly assessed factors in epidemiological analyses of the effects of maternal fever on the fetus.

Comment: I agree that the meaning of "enduring" here is ambiguous.  My gut instinct is it means *"fevers that don't go away"* but I couldn't say for sure without more context.

Comment: The simplest explanation is that they mean *enduring* in the sense of *ongoing*—an adjective. Absent any clear evidence that they mean *enduring fevers* to be a gerund phrase, you should assume they mean *continuing*. Really, you need to torture logic to make it mean anything else.